# Replace one part of a pattern in a string/sentence?

Tags: python, regex

There is a text blob for example

```
"Text blob1. Text blob2. Text blob3 45.6%. Text blob4."
```

I want to replace the dots i.e. `"."` with space `" "`. But at the same time, dots appearing between numbers should be retained. For example, the previous example should be converted to:

```
"Text blob1 Text blob2 Text blob3 45.6% Text blob4"
```

If I use:

```
p = re.compile('\.')
s = p.sub(' ', s)
```

It replaces all dots with space.

Any suggestions on what pattern or method works here?

Comment: what do you mean by "dots appearing between numbers should be retained"

Comment: @Hussain I guess exactly what it sounds like

Comment: Now i got it. @HarshalParekh :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
\.(?!(?<=\d\.)\d)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/M0lu6Y/1). This expression will match any dot that has no digit after it that is preceded with a digit and a dot.

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: This time I'm really going to study it. It's a deceivingly simple problem, but I always feel some panic when I see those positive and negative look behind values. ?!?>?=<?!= :-))

Answer (score 0):

You might not need regex here. Replace a dot-space with a space.

```
s.replace('. ', ' ')
```

That isn't good enough if you have any periods followed by a newline or that terminate the string, but you still wouldn't need a regex:

```
s.replace('. ', ' ').replace('.\n', '\n').rstrip('.')
```

Comment: Should mention that it will fail if the input is like `"Test blob1.Text blob2"`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the string were

```
A.B.C blob3 45.6%. Text blob4.
```

**Match all periods other than those both preceded and followed by a digit**

If after replacements, the string

```
A B C blob3 45.6% Text blob4
```

were desired, one could use `re.sub` with the regular expression

```
r'(?<!\d)\.|\.(?!\d)'
```

to replace matches of periods with empty strings.

The regex reads, "match a period that is not preceded by a character other than a digit or is not followed by a character other than a digit".

[Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/VKMQX4/1/)

The double-negative is employed to match a period at the beginning or end of the string. One could instead use the logical equivalent:

```
r'(?<=^|\D)\.|\.(?=\D|$)'
```

**Match all periods except those both preceded and followed by a whitespace character**

On the other hand, if, after substitutions, the string

```
A.B.C blob3 45.6% Text blob4
```

were desired one could use `re.sub` with the regular expression

```
r'(?<!\S)\.|\.(?!\S)'
```

to replace matches of periods with empty strings.

This regex reads, "match a period that is not preceded by a character other than a whitespace or is not followed by a character other than a whitespace".

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/VKMQX4/2/)

One could instead use the logical equivalent:

```
r'(?<=^|\s)\.|\.(?=\s|$)'
```